# Print login page url in node.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming, uri

It seems nevertheless rather simple, but I do not find the solution.

How to print in node.tpl.php the url of the login page?

The url has to serve for a link:

```
<a href="<?php print ... ?>"><span>Login</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this if you just want the URL:

```
<?php print url('user/login'); ?>
```

If you want to print a link:

```
<?php print l(t('Login'), 'user/login'); ?>
```

And in your case it would be:

```
<?php print l('<span>' . t('Login') . '</span>', 'user/login', array('html' => TRUE)); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Aram, i have an error: page not found. I indeed need only the url. It is the difficulty. For information I use pathauto, I do not know if it interferes.

Comment: Not completely clear; so when you go to `yourwebsite.com/user/login` you get a 404?

Comment: No, i have a 404 when I click the generated link. The page `yourwebsite.com/user/login` works. The error message is : `The page "/mysite/articles/user/login " was not found`.